# How do I select class within a class or a tag using Javascript getElementsByClass() function?

Tags: javascript, class, select, getelementsbyclassname

In jQuery it would simply be

```
$("a.class").randommethod();
```

or

```
$(".class1 .class2").randommethod();
```

How do I achieve the same effect using pure Javascript? (I'm editing a open-source software for personal use and it doesn't use jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it using `getElementsByClassName`. You would need to use something more like `querySelectorAll`, which accepts CSS style selectors.

```
var result = document.querySelectorAll('.class1 .class2');
```

You should note that neither method has full cross-browser support. That's why people use javascript libraries. If you don't need to support older browsers, then `querySelectorAll` is a good choice.

Another option is to use [the `Sizzle` selector engine](http://sizzlejs.com) that jQuery uses.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your own selector engine, or use an established one such as sizzle (http://sizzlejs.com/), which is used by jQuery.